# AWS Cloudwatch Insights - parse a string as JSON

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

Sending JSON logs to AWS Cloudwatch - mostly it works great, but once in awhile, I may get a log entry that isn't quite pure JSON (or at least, oddly formatted).  Here's an example of a single log entry from a Slack bot:

```
{"message": "Unhandled request ({'token': 'ezyBLAHBLAHBLAHDSDFL59', 'team_id': 'TF3BLAHBLAH', 'api_app_id': 'A01EBLAHBLAH', 'event': {'client_msg_id': '5ablahbd-blah-blah-blah-ffe18343blah', 'type': 'message', 'text': 'thanks', 'user': 'UFBLAHBLAH', 'ts': '1605733337.001300', 'team': 'TF3BLAHBLAH', 'blocks': [{'type': 'rich_text', 'block_id': 'gucN', 'elements': [{'type': 'rich_text_section', 'elements': [{'type': 'text', 'text': 'thanks'}]}]}], 'channel': 'D01BLAHBLAH', 'event_ts': '1605733337.001300', 'channel_type': 'im'}, 'type': 'event_callback', 'event_id': 'Ev0BLAHBLAH', 'event_time': 1605733337, 'authorizations': [{'enterprise_id': None, 'team_id': 'TFBLAHBLAH', 'user_id': 'U01BLAHBLAH', 'is_bot': True, 'is_enterprise_install': False}], 'is_ext_shared_channel': False, 'event_context': '1-message-TFBLAHBLAHV-D0BLAHBLAH'})", "level": "WARNING", "name": "slack_bolt.App", "time": "2020-11-18T21:08:18.184+00:00"}
```

So it is valid JSON, and Cloudwatch correctly parses what is there, but the bulk of the details of the unhandled request are trapped inside a string:

```
"message" : "Unhandled request(<lots_of_json>)"
"level": "WARNING"
"name": "slack_bolt.App"
"time": "2020-11-18T21:08:18.184+00:00"
```

What I WANT to get out of there is the `<lots_of_json>` part, and I want to have it interpreted as JSON - be able to report, sort, and aggregate on those fields, etc.

I can get about this far in a Cloudwatch Insights query:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter message like 'Unhandled request'
| parse message 'Unhandled request (*)' as unhandled_payload
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

And then this gives me the `<lots_of_json>` string in the ephemeral field `unhandled_payload`

Now how can I get that `unhandled_payload` JSON-formatted string parsed as JSON?  The `parse` command only accepts globs or regexes and using either of those for this sounds... unpleasant.  There must be a command to parse a JSON string, right?  What is it?

("go fix the logging in the app" is not an acceptable answer for the purposes of this question)

Answer (score 1):

I'd love to know the solution. Or at least how the f*** to remove the "web:" prefix in log groups in order to properly log JSONs